# Anonymous user making edits to answers

Tags: discussion, editing, specific-question

An anonymous user is making edits to [Source of water for the Great Artesian Basin in Australia](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/4466/source-of-water-for-the-great-artesian-basin-in-australia/17165#17165) that seem to go a little far - I have already rejected one as *conflicting with the author's intent*, and one as *no improvement whatsoever*.

It smells as if someone is trying to put his (her) opinions in - instead of answering himself, or using comments instead of edits.

I cannot see if it really is the same anonymous user (there were several hours in between).

1. Can anyone dig up more specif info?
2. Is special action required or will the usual review processes suffice?

Answer (score 2):

Anyone with access to moderator tools can look at:

- [rejected suggested edits](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com//tools/suggested-edits?filter=week&tab=Rejected) in the suggested-edits tool
- [all suggested edits](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/history) in the review tool

This privilege requires 2K reputation on a beta site such as ours.  Without this, the former link will work not at all and the latter link will only show your own suggested edits.

I can't think of any special action we can take beyond the usual review process. Remain vigilant, check carefully what edits are accepted or not.

Although there is a way for moderators to check whether different anonymous edits are coming from the same IP address, I'm not sure if it would be useful or appropriate in this case, as such checks are normally limited to severe cases.